# Trying to Clone Account Record And its Related List but only Getting few fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

Trying to Clone Account Record And its Related Contacts.. but i am only getting those fields i retrieved from SOQL. To get all Fields Value do i need to retrieve all value from Account and Contact first?

```
global class CloneAccountRecordController 
{
    Public Id accId;
    public CloneAccountRecordController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
    public PageReference cloneRecord()
    {
        List<Contact> conCopyList = new List<Contact>();
        Account accSobj = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id =:accId];
        Account accCopy = accSobj.Clone(false,true);
        insert accCopy;
        List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =:accSobj.Id];
        for(Contact conSobj : conList)
        {
            Contact conCopy = conSobj.Clone(false,true);
            conCopy.AccountId = accCopy.Id;
            conCopyList.add(conCopy);
        }
        insert conCopyList;
        PageReference Page = new PageReference('https://playful-raccoon-a2tqu9-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/001/o');
        Page.setRedirect(true);
        return Page;
    }
}
```

VF Page - Calling in Custom Button

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" action="{!cloneRecord}" extensions="CloneAccountRecordController" >
</apex:page>
```

Comment: yes, all fields needs to be queried

Comment: So i need to use Schema Class here.. right?

Comment: It might be a case in order to query all fields dynamically

Comment: Sure, Thanks @kurunve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dynamic SOQL with the help of `getDescribe()`

```
List<String> accountFields = new List<String>(Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
        String soqlAccount = ''+ ' select ' + String.join(accountFields, ',')+ ' from Account'+ ' where Id =:accountId';
```

You can try like this

```
global class CloneAccountRecordController 
{
    Public Id accountId;    //To get Current Account Id
    public CloneAccountRecordController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)     //Constructor
    {
        //Adding Current Account Id to variable 'accountId'
        accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
    public PageReference cloneRecord()
    {
        //Getting all fields of Account to Clone all field value using Dynamic SOQL
        List<String> accountFields = new List<String>(Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
        String soqlAccount = ''+ ' select ' + String.join(accountFields, ',')+ ' from Account'+ ' where Id =:accountId';
        Account accSobj = Database.query(soqlAccount);
        Account accCopy = accSobj.Clone(false,true);
        insert accCopy;

        List<Contact> conCopyList = new List<Contact>();
        //Getting all fields of Contact to Clone all field value using Dynamic SOQL
        List<String> contactFields = new List<String>(Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
        String soqlContact = ''+ ' select ' + String.join(contactFields, ',')+ ' from Contact'+ ' where AccountId =:accountId';
        List<Contact> conList = Database.query(soqlContact);

        for(Contact conSobj : conList)
        {
            Contact conCopy = conSobj.Clone(false,true);
            conCopy.AccountId = accCopy.Id;
            conCopyList.add(conCopy);
        }
        insert conCopyList;

        PageReference Page = new PageReference('https://playful-raccoon-a2tqu9-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/001/o');
        Page.setRedirect(true);
        return Page;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank You @Dave. This is helpfull :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:-

```
string queryString ='SELECT ' + getObjectFields('Opportunity') + 'From Opportunity where id=:OppId ';
```

Getting all the fields of an object by passing an object name:-

```
public static String getObjectFields(String objectName) {
        String sQuery = '';
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        for(Schema.SObjectField column: objectFieldMap.values()) {
            //system.debug('column Name is ' + column + 'column permission' + column.getDescribe().isUpdateable());
            sQuery += column+', ';
        }
        sQuery = sQuery.substring(0, sQuery.length()-2);
        sQuery += ' ';
        return sQuery;
    }
```

It will fix your problem and make sure your cloned record will have all the field values.

Comment: Thanks @Sanket Kumar!. Appreciate for the help.